# Does Raspbian close applications if there is no disk space left?

Tags: raspbian, sd-card

I wrote an app for my raspberry pi using .Net Core.
I start it when someone logs in via a new line in the /etc/profile.
For simplicity let's say that the app just has an infinite loop and waits for console inputs of the user.

The app ran fine for the last few weeks. Since yesterday my app starts and gets exited after some seconds without any exception. Now I looking for the reason.

I noticed that there is no more disk space free on the SD card. Even nano gives me a warning when opening a file because it can't create one of its temporary files.
Could it be that I need some more free space o  n the disk in order to keep my program running? Is there some kind of service in Raspbian that could kill my app because of that?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by "disk space"? Do you mean RAM?

Comment: No, I mean actual disk space on the SD card.

Comment: Do some housekeeping. Get rid of junk in /tmp, get rid of junk in /var/log. Uninstall software packages you don't need. Migrate the system from the current SDCard to a 32GB (or larger one).

Answer (score 1):

Many programs make use of temporary files.

If the temporary file can not be created that program will fail.

If there is no spare SD card space then temporary files can not be created there and so programs which need temporary files will fail.

The solution is to create more space by deleting unneeded files from the SD card.